# サンプルアプリ４−１がタップしても止まりません。

Tags: monaca

公式ガイドブックを購入して勉強を始めたばかりです。サンプルアプリ４−１を作成しましたが、アニメーションは動きますが、画面をタップしても止まりません。

https://ja.monaca.io/book/support/

上記のURLよりサンプルアプリをダウンロードしても同じ結果になります。どこがいけないのでしょうか？

```
  function toggleAnimation() {
      $(".run").toggleClass("stop");
  }
```

２行目の前後にそれぞれ「console.log」で入れて実行しましたが、２行目の前のログは出力されましたが、後ろのログは出力されません。

解析の方法など、解決するための方法でも構いません。
ご教授をお願いします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。解決しました。
ちなみにどのコンポーネントがどのような機能があるのかというのは、どのようにすれば解るのでしょうか？

Comment: 解決したのであれば回答を承認してください。また、質問にコメントを行っても回答者には通知されません。回答に対してコメントを行いましょう。

Answer (score 1):

サンプルアプリ`4-1.zip`をダウンロードし、`Import Project`からインポートして動作させましたが、プレビューおよびMonacaデバッガーで問題なくタップで停止、再生します。
MonacaクラウドIDEから`ファイル`→`JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除`と選択し、`jQuery(Monaca Version)`が追加されているか確認してみてください。